# Simple remote administration agent software

Tags: untagged

I am looking for a simple remote control, agent based software to perform simple commands to 
geographically dispersed workstations.

I am looking for something similar to Microsoft Intune.

I am open to suggestions: from standalone software to frameworks or technologies like WinRM.

Edit: simple commands are power off/reboot, services control: start/stop/reboot.

Comment: If you're looking for something like Windows Intune then why not just use Windows Intune?

Comment: It is a good candidate but it works only with Windows Professional and upper versions. And second it installs about 9 different agents.

Comment: give an example of "perform simple commands"? Sounds like you may just need wmic or powershells gwmi capabilities which are part of the os.  Think everything intune does can be emulated with wmi.

Comment: I added few examples of simple commands.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Kaseya? I did a little work for a firm that used this, as much as I never fully got to grips with it, there seemed like a lot of functionality that will probably be relevant to your needs.

However, I personally felt more comfy either having a site to site vpn or vpn'ing into the site and remotely accessing the pc.